# TYPO3: pass a frontend session variable to the page with TypoScript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-11.x

I have TYPO3 v11.

In my extension controller I set a session variable:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', "typows_accessToken",$accessToken->getToken());
```

It works.

Now i want to pass it to page data.

I tried:

```
[globalVar = session:ses|typows_accessToken]
page.10.variables.tokensessione=TEXT
page.10.variables.tokensessione.value = session:ses|typows_accessToken 
[global]
```

But it doesn't work.

There is a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `data` instead of `value`:

```
[globalVar = session:ses|typows_accessToken]
page.10.variables.tokensessione = TEXT
page.10.variables.tokensessione.data = session:ses|typows_accessToken 
[global]
```

Comment: it is still empty

Comment: I think that is empty session:ses|typows_accessToken